# animate different buttons to the correct location

Tags: swift

How can i animate different buttons? i make 16 buttons in an for loop:

```
for i in 1..<17
{
    if(i == 5 || i == 9 || i == 13){
        added = 0
        moveToBottom += 60
    }
    var button = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(CGFloat(Int(middleWidth) + added), CGFloat(moveToBottom), 50, 50))
    self.view.addSubview(button)

    UIView.animateWithDuration(2, animations:{
        button.frame = CGRectMake(CGFloat(Int(middleWidth) + added), CGFloat(Int(middleHeight) + moveToBottom), 50, 50)
    },completion: nil )
}
```

And i animate them to the correct place, but what i get is that all the buttons do on the exact same time the animation. That is not what i want, the buttons must animate on different times to its location, how can i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you means add animation to the button one by one ?

try this function, and configure the delay parameter.

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(duration: NSTimeInterval, delay: NSTimeInterval, options: UIViewAnimationOptions, animations: { () -> Void in
  // your animate code...
}, completion:
  // completion block ....
)
```

In your condition, write this instead:

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(2, delay: 2*(i-1), options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveLinear, animations: { () -> Void in
    button.frame = CGRectMake(CGFloat(Int(middleWidth) + added), CGFloat(Int(middleHeight) + moveToBottom), 50, 50)
}, completion: nil)
```